# Hibernate 4+spring3.2 integration error

Tags: spring-mvc, hibernate-4.x

I am trying to implement spring mvc 3.2 with hibernate 4. I have inclided all jars incliding `hibernate.jpa.2.0.1` while starting the application I am getting exception.

exception stack given bellow.

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/hibernate-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint.name()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1486)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:589)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint.name()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.TableBinder.buildUniqueConstraintHolders(TableBinder.java:548)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:563)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3443)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3397)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1341)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1737)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1788)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:242)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:372)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:357)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1483)
    ... 27 more
Dec 12, 2012 1:53:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Dec 12, 2012 1:53:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/lifekareremote2] startup failed due to previous errors
Dec 12, 2012 1:53:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Dec 12, 2012 1:53:52 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/lifekareremote2] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Dec 12, 2012 1:53:52 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/lifekareremote2] appears to have started a thread named [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Dec 12, 2012 1:53:52 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/lifekareremote2] appears to have started a thread named [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Dec 12, 2012 1:53:52 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/lifekareremote2] appears to have started a thread named [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Dec 12, 2012 1:53:52 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/lifekareremote2] appears to have started a thread named [MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Dec 12, 2012 1:53:52 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/lifekareremote2] appears to have started a thread named [Resource Destroyer in BasicResourcePool.close()] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
```

Comment: It seems that there is hibernate-jpa-1.0-api JAR somewhere around lying in your classpath. And because of which your hibernate.jpa.2.0.1  is not getting loaded. I would suggest to check all the JAR files in your classpath and remove any of the old JPA versions.

Comment: I have checked it. i removed all unique constants and tried. i am getting exception at one to many annotation exception.

Comment: The exception `Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint.name()Ljava/lang/String;`
 clearly says that you do not have correct version of hibernate-jpa-2 jar in your classpath. If you using Maven for build then it may happens that hibernate-jpa-1 jar is getting loaded through transitive dependencies.

Comment: I have downloaded distribution and added all jars provided by hibernate 4

Comment: thanks viralpatel for replay. i got the solution i have a jar called ejb-persistence-1.0.jar and persistence-api-1.0.jar. i have removed both from project. it is working fine.